# Why image name not showing in the form field for update?

Tags: jquery, forms, file

I wonder why image name not appearing in the value of the file field while when im trying to use different type of field the Image name is showing.

I have the jQuery that feeling image name from database and put the value in the form field but it work fine on the field type text, and not field type file how can I solve it

Look my single line of code

```
$('#file').value(data.image);

//My input field not replaced by that image, it replace when I change type="file" to type="text"
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

Comment: You cannot put value inside input type file. Best way is to set hidden input with the value from your db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `DataTransfer()` to set value of the input type file.

In your case let's say `data.image` is `yourImageFromDatabase.jpg`.

```js
let  sample =   new DataTransfer(); 
sample.items.add(new File(['yourFile'], 'yourImageFromDatabase.jpg')); //get "yourImageFromDatabase" value from `data.image`
file.files = sample.files;

// Get filename
 let name = $('#file').val().split('\\').pop();;
 console.log(name);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

Comment: what does file.files the file keyword mean, because it say undefined file typoerror  @Shree

Comment: Run snippet it's work. Read document about [DataTransfer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer).  Understand your code how it works. That's the best way to programming. Good luck.